# Validation errors are not visible partialView in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view with a DropDownList control and a textbox.

When nothing is selected or no text is entered the ModelState.IsValid is FALSE

BUT I can see no validation errors displayed annotated on my properties.

Why is that? I can see in the ModelState.Value.Errors property there is an "Name is

missing" for example.

When I confirm the invalid view I see this in my output window:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll


public ActionResult Edit()
{
    return LoadEditTemplates();
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(EditTemplateListViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && !_templateDataProvider.TemplateExists(viewModel.Name))
    {
        Template template = Mapper.Map<EditTemplateListViewModel, Template>(viewModel);
        _templateDataProvider.UpdateTemplate(template);
        return new JsonNetResult(new { success = true });
    }

    return PartialView(viewModel);
}

private ActionResult LoadEditTemplates()
{
    var templates = _templateDataProvider.GetTemplates();
    EditTemplateListViewModel editTemplateViewModel = new EditTemplateListViewModel()
    {
        DisplayList = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Template>, IEnumerable<TemplateViewModel>>(templates),
    };
    return PartialView(editTemplateViewModel);
}

public class EditTemplateListViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "No template selected.")]
        public int TemplateId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is missing")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<TemplateViewModel> DisplayList { get; set; }      
    }

@model ITMS.Web.Models.EditTemplateListViewModel

@*Remote Validation*@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Template"))
{       
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TemplateId, new SelectList(Model.DisplayList, "TemplateId", "Name"), new { @class = "listviewmodel" })

    <p class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</p>
    <p class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)</p>
    <p class="editor-field">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</p>   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I returned the data from the post action I realized the Argument cast exception because I did not pass data for example to the SelectItem list "DisplayList". It was null and thus bang...

I just filled the missing data to redisplay the view and the errors are visible :) heck... I already stepped in that failure once...

Answer (score 1):

Insated  Of using Html,BeginForm use Ajax.BeginForm to submit your partial view

```
   //In partial View 


<div id="targetId">
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Update", "Template", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST", UpdateTargetId="targetId"}))
        {       
            @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TemplateId, new SelectList(Model.DisplayList, "TemplateId", "Name"), new { @class = "listviewmodel" })

            <p class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</p>
            <p class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)</p>
            <p class="editor-field">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</p>   
        }
```

return type of Partial view is **String** so you can catch  it at server side, in ajax option you must be specify HttpMethod and UpdateTargetId where you want to show your result in view.here i am quoted your Ajax.BegionForm with div and given UpdateTargetId is Div Id so that if error will occur it append view in same div

In Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public string Update(EditTemplateListViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && !_templateDataProvider.TemplateExists(viewModel.Name))
    {
        Template template = Mapper.Map<EditTemplateListViewModel, Template>(viewModel);
        _templateDataProvider.UpdateTemplate(template);
        return new JsonNetResult(new { success = true });
    }

    return RenderPartialViewToString("PartialViewName",viewModel);
}



protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

by passing partialViewName and Model to RenderPartialViewToStringit will return you **RenderHtml** of View.

NOTE: before using  Ajax.BeginForm make sure add following script.

Comment: I am already using Ajax.BeginForm by using Jquery Ajax form post. Ajax.BeginForm is just the MVC "wrapper".

Comment: I have checked your code which is from here: http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/ ... I can not resolve the class Config.Url.ToString() What is that Config class?

Comment: Elisa i have not getting about Config.Url.toString() so can you please me some more detail about it where you have used it in code.

Answer (score 0):

Since server side code is working fine, I would suggest to check if required JQuery libraries are loaded properly.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Did not help. Just the opposite. When I open the jquery dialog with the partial view I get lots of exceptions in the output window.

Comment: If partial view is loaded asynchronously, validation plugin needs to be reinitialized again. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005052/trouble-getting-unobtrusive-validation-working-with-mvc-3-on-jquery-ajax-post and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516245/how-to-check-if-a-div-is-valid-with-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: all my partial views are loaded async. I never needed any further jquery library except the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js". And on my side there is no dynamic content.

Comment: Tonight I will put together a running sample so you see.